Can't define a global variable that has a type within a function
I'm trying to create a function that reloads a global bank:
import json

type Bank = dict[str, dict[str: int | float]]

def get_ball() -> None:
    """
    _summary_
    Reloads the bank dict from the bank.json file
    """
    global bank
    with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
        bank: Bank = json.load(f)  # Error
        # bank = json.load(f)      # Works fine
    print(bank)

get_ball()
print(bank)

But it raises a SyntaxError: annotated name 'bank' can't be global
When it doesn't have an assigned type it works just fine (see the commented out line). What do I have to do?

Why don't you declare the type in the global scope, before the function?

Or better yet, don't use a global at all.  get_ball could return a dict[str, dict[str: int | float]] instead of loading it into a global.  That way you can write a test for get_ball.  It's generally best to avoid globals.

Presumably, bank (as a global) already has a type; you shouldn't need to annotate it "again".

The misconception here is that code like bank = json.load(f) does not "define" the global. It is the same kind of assignment as any other. SImilarly, global bank doesn't "define" the global either. It simply tells Python that bank within the function should mean a name in the global namespace. The reason for the limitation is clear: what if you tried to make a conflicting annotation in a different function?

You should declare it outside function
type Bank = dict[str, dict[str: int | float]]

#bank:Bank
bank:Bank = {}  # or with default value at start

def get_ball() -> None:
    """
    _summary_
    Reloads the bank dict from the bank.json file
    """
    global bank
    
    with open("bank.json") as f:
        bank = json.load(f)

    print(bank)

get_ball()
print(bank)


But it would be better if you wouldn't use global at all
import json

type Bank = dict[str, dict[str: int | float]]

def get_ball() -> Bank:
    """
    _summary_
    Reloads the bank dict from the bank.json file
    """
    
    bank:Bank = {}  # default value at start
    
    with open("bank.json") as f:
        bank = json.load(f)

    return bank

data:Bank = get_ball()
print(data)


Really thanks I know I shouldn't use global but I'm working with that value across whole module and more. I don't really focus on how long that will take
